# Bluetooth mouse randomly stops working

Tags: fedora, x11, bluetooth, mouse

With the new updates to F39, my MX Master mouse stops working at random intervals.  It could be a few seconds to an hour or more.  Bluetooth still thinks the mouse is connected, which I know because when I have my trackpad set to `'disabled-on-external-mouse'`, neither of them works.

To get the mouse to work, I have to put the computer to sleep and then immediately wake it up again or I tell bt to disconnect from the mouse and reconnect and that works.

Turning the mouse off and back on doesn't work--when I turn it off, bluetooth still thinks it's connected.  If I turn bluetooth off and try to turn it back on, it doesn't turn on.  The toggle switch flickers but bt won't turn back on.

I've tried using different kernels 6.4 through the current kernel (6.6.6), but none of them keep it working reliably. This didn't happen until I upgraded to F39 from F38 a couple weeks ago.

The logs indicate that my bt may be timing out: `Bluetooth: hci1: command 0x0c01 tx timeout`, but there are alot of msgs from xorg removing the device: `(II) config/udev: removing device MX Master Mouse`, so maybe it's the windowing system (doesn't make sense to me, but I'm no psychometrist).  I use x because some of my apps don't like wayland yet.

[Link to logs](https://file.io/zjDE3vuVy0xy)

## System Details Report

---

### Report details

- **Date generated:**                              2023-12-19 13:14:09

### Hardware Information:

- **Hardware Model:**                              Lenovo ThinkPad L15 Gen 2a
- **Memory:**                                      16.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 5850U with Radeon™ Graphics × 16
- **Graphics:**                                    AMD Radeon™ Graphics
- **Disk Capacity:**                               (null)

### Software Information:

- **Firmware Version:**                            R1KET43W (1.28 )
- **OS Name:**                                     Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition)
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               45.2
- **Windowing System:**                            X11
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.6.6-200.fc39.x86_64